# C# and SQLGeometry: Combining Database Rows and WPF

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I'm pretty sure I want to use the SqlGeometry datatype to store a bunch of polygons in a database. Does the SqlGeometry type inter-operate into C# and WPF.  Can you just directly cast an SqlGeometry to a Shape or Path?

Secondly,  Is it possible to store more than 1 polygon in a single SqlGeometry column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This link shows how to view SqlGeometry visually in C#:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/sqlgeometry.aspx

This link shows how to manipulate SqlGeometry data types in C#:
http://www.nickharris.net/tag/geometry-data-type/

Regarding multiple polygons per SqlGemotry column, I don't think you can do this per: http://barendgehrels.blogspot.com/2011_04_01_archive.html which converts multi-geometry to a list of SqlGeometry.

Answer (score 0):

SqlGeometry and WPF Geometries are independent libraries. You would need to do a conversion.

You can only store one geometry per column, but a geometry can be an MultiPolygon or a GeometryCollection. Both are ways to store more Polygons in one column. So, yes.